# Resolve conflicts without merge target branch

Tags: git

I am working on feature branch, which cut from main `branch - 1`, and suppose to merge in main `branch - 2`. (This is bit awkward git flow we are using in project)

Now, when raising PR to `branch - 2`, I see merge conflicts in two files. I don't want to take pull of `branch - 2` in my code due to other ongoing work by other team members. Hence, I need a way to resolve that merge conflicts without merge back `branch - 2` in my feature branch.

It will be great if anyone know how this can be done in intelliJidea, OR Else, commands would be sufficient.

Comment: Stash the ongoing work, fix the conflict, merge it, pop your stash

Comment: If you don't want to merge branch-2 into your feature, why are you raising a PR to branch-2?

Comment: I have other solution, like cherry pick etc, but wondering, Is there any trick.

Comment: @zdhim Is branch-2 large and you're trying to get a specific portion of branch-2, like a bug fix or refactoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, when raising PR to branch - 2...

If you're raising a PR to branch-2, presumably you would like to merge with branch-2. But you don't want to merge with branch-2.

> Hence, I need a way to resolve that merge conflicts without merge back branch - 2 in my feature branch.

You could, but such a partial merge would likely be broken code.

For example, let's say you both refactored a function to work a bit differently. This results in a conflict. How do you meaningfully resolve this conflict without also merging in the rest of the changes from branch-2?

If you resolve it by accepting branch-2's changes, you also need to accept branch-2's changes to where the function is called. If you resolve it by accepting your own changes, you'll have to resolve conflicts with where branch-2 changed function calls later.

---

I'm going to guess branch-2 is a large feature branch with a lot of independent fixes mixed in and you only want the fixes. In this case, make a new branch off branch-1, cherry pick just the fixes, and get that merged. Now everyone can access the fixes without also dragging in the rest of branch-2.

Rebase (or merge) your feature branch onto branch-1 to get the fixes.

Also rebase (or merge) branch-2 onto branch-1. This simplifies branch-2.

To draw it out. Your repo looks like this.

```
A - B - C [branch-1]
        |\
        | D - E - F [branch-2]
        \
         G - H - I [feature]
```

You want only commit E. Make a new branch off branch-1.

```
$ git checkout -b fix branch-1

          [fix]
A - B - C [branch-1]
        |\
        | D - E - F [branch-2]
        \
         G - H - I [feature]
```

Cherry pick E.

```
$ git cherry-pick E
          E1 [fix]
         /
A - B - C [branch-1]
        |\
        | D - E - F [branch-2]
        \
         G - H - I [feature]
```

Get it merged into branch-1 like any other PR.

```
          E1
         /  \
A - B - C --- M [branch-1]
        |\
        | D - E - F [branch-2]
        \
         G - H - I [feature]
```

Rebase both branches on top of the new branch-1.

```
$ git checkout branch-2
$ git rebase branch-1
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase branch-1

          E1
         /  \
A - B - C --- M [branch-1]
              |\
              | D - F [branch-2]
              \
               G - H - I [feature]
```

Note how E goes away on branch-2 because it is redundant with E1.